# Plot multiple datasets with ListPlot and SlideRegulators

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, slider

I recently got into Mathematica and have a script from my professor, which calculates and plots some values zR*Tan[phi] + z0 + R1 from different variables.
The variables can be adjusted by a slide.
I now added another variable R2 and want to plot the values in the same plot, so I can compare values for R1 and R2.

Here is my code:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Row[Text[Style[#, FontFamily -> "Helvetica",18]] & /@ {"Anzahl der Messpunkte: ", 
   Length[Table[{phi/Pi*180, zR*Tan[phi] + z0}, {phi, -90 Degree,90 Degree, Schrittweite Degree}]]}],
   ListPlot[Table[{phi/Pi*180, zR*Tan[phi] + z0 + R1}, {phi, -85 Degree,85 Degree, Schrittweite Degree}],
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium],
    LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 18],
    AxesLabel -> {"\[Phi][\[Degree]]", "z[mm]"},
    Ticks -> {Table[phi, {phi, -90, 90, 10}], Automatic},
    ImageSize -> 1000],
   Prepend[N[Table[{phi/Pi*180, zR*Tan[phi] + z0 +R1, zR*Tan[phi] + z0 + R2}, {phi, -85 Degree, 85 Degree, Schrittweite Degree}]], {"\[Phi][\[Degree]]", "z[mm]", 
  "z[mm]"}] // MatrixForm}], {{zR, 20, "Rayleigh-Länge [mm]"}, 1, 100,1}, {{z0, 125, "Position Strahltaille [mm]"}, 0, 250,1}, {{Schrittweite, 2, "Schrittweite [\[Degree]]"}, .5,5, .5}, {{R1, 200, "Radius_1 [mm]"}, 100, 1000,50}, {{R2, 500, "Radius_2 [mm]"}, 100, 1000, 50}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) with `PlotRange->All`

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{Row[
    Text[Style[#, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
        18]] & /@ {"Anzahl der Messpunkte: ", 
      Length[Table[{phi/Pi*180, zR*Tan[phi] + z0}, {phi, -90 Degree, 
         90 Degree, Schrittweite Degree}]]}],


   Show[{
     ListPlot[
      Table[{phi/Pi*180, zR*Tan[phi] + z0 + R1}, {phi, -85 Degree, 
        85 Degree, Schrittweite Degree}], 
      PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], 
      LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 18], 
      AxesLabel -> {"\[Phi][\[Degree]]", "z[mm]"}, 
      Ticks -> {Table[phi, {phi, -90, 90, 10}], Automatic}, 
      ImageSize -> 600]
     ,
     ListPlot[
      Table[{phi/Pi*180, zR*Tan[phi] + z0 + R2}, {phi, -85 Degree, 
        85 Degree, Schrittweite Degree}], 
      PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], 
      LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 18], 
      AxesLabel -> {"\[Phi][\[Degree]]", "z[mm]"}, 
      Ticks -> {Table[phi, {phi, -90, 90, 10}], Automatic}, 
      ImageSize -> 600]
     }, PlotRange -> All]
   ,

   Prepend[
     N[Table[{phi/Pi*180, zR*Tan[phi] + z0 + R1, 
        zR*Tan[phi] + z0 + R2}, {phi, -85 Degree, 85 Degree, 
        Schrittweite Degree}]], {"\[Phi][\[Degree]]", "z[mm]", 
      "z[mm]"}] // MatrixForm}],

 {{zR, 20, "Rayleigh-Länge [mm]"}, 1, 100, 
  1}, {{z0, 125, "Position Strahltaille [mm]"}, 0, 250, 
  1}, {{Schrittweite, 2, "Schrittweite [\[Degree]]"}, .5, 
  5, .5}, {{R1, 200, "Radius_1 [mm]"}, 100, 1000, 
  50}, {{R2, 500, "Radius_2 [mm]"}, 100, 1000, 50}]
```

I would implore you to read through the docs and take the time to understand what I've done in the above, since if I understand the query correctly I've gone out of my way to do all the work for you.

If I misunderstood something please let me know.

Comment: thank you. It works fine!
Yes, I'm right into it and trying to undertand it.